# Automatic tag-inferred syntax highlighting does not work in SO for LaTeX

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

It seems that the automatic tag-inferred syntax-highlighting doesn't work for latex code when adding the [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) tag on stackoverflow.

[image]

As one can see the code block syntax is not highlighted, even with added tag. Adding `<!-- language: lang-latex -->` before the code block enables correctly the highlighting, so the functionality is there.

However, repeating the same example with Python code and the `python` tag enables the syntax highlighting already without the `<!-- ... -->` HTML tag. So there seems be something odd in inferring the syntax from the `latex` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like LaTeX highlighting support is a [relatively new addition to the supported list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234056/can-we-have-more-tag-based-syntax-highlighting-options/249799#249799), so no default was yet set for the tag.

I've now switched the tag default to use `lang-latex`, lets see how that goes:

[image: excerpt of tag wiki pag, showing the 'syntax highlighting' code language dropdown box that moderators see, set to <code>lang-latex</code>]